# Set latch and Or gates

Tags: latch

I'm really new to Electrical circuits so please bear with me.
 I studied how set latch works :firstly, input 0 then Q(let's say output and it's 0 i  this case) feedback another input resulting output 0. Then if I input 1, the output Q turns into 1, as a result it latches 1.

Here's my question. How do you know that output Q is 0 in the first place even though there is only one input gets 0 (the other input is affected by the output)?

Comment: Is this a study room to find a simple answer already in textbooks and datasheets?

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt, textbooks like to start out an explanation with, "Assume that..." and then never explain why you're assuming it. Datasheets aren't in the business of explaining basics to beginners.

Comment: Yes all steps in learning have pre-requisites in experience and the best tools are a web search engine and knowing how to use key words with -notthis

Comment: The answer here is : you never assume and use a power on Reset or set.

Comment: @Annie example: https://www.google.ca/search?client=safari&hl=en-ca&ei=4QUHW4WkB6TKjwSb1q-gAg&q=output+Q+is+0+in+the+first+place+flip+flop&oq=output+Q+is+0+in+the+first+place+flip+flop&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-serp.3..33i21.14264.17819..18321...0....195.1187.5j5......0....1.........0i71j33i160.vjjkJbs0xFU%3D. I prefer to teach how to fish than give free fish answers unless based on unique experience. Otherwise it gets too redundant and time waster.

Comment: Another situation to force Q may be to initialize a process then execute, sample or count inputs and latch on the clock active edge.

Answer (score 2):

When analyzing the behavior of a latch when the inputs are in the "hold" condition you don't know what the stored state of the latch actually is. So, you assume that the stored state is a '1' and verify that all of the other signals in the latch will be consistent with that assumption. Then, you assume that the stored state is a '0' and verify that all other signals are consistent with the new assumption. If so, then you have a valid latch circuit and you've identified the input conditions that cause the latch to retain its state.

By the way, you can't make a latch from two OR gates. You need to use inverting gates such as the NOR or NAND.